# Async Await not working reading data from Firebase with react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

This is my current code (see image)
I need my OwnProfile function to wait for my GetUsername function to finish reading data from firebase before continuing.
I tried async await, but it is not working as shown in the terminal where line 52 and 54 are used before GetUsername has gotten the data.

Anyone got any tips to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You're not awaiting `GetUsername()`. Try `const data = await GetUsername();`

Comment: Thanks! But it is still giving the same order output in the terminal :(

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [reference docs for `on`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Query#on) you'll see that it doesn't return a `Promise`, so you can't `await` its results. Use `once` (or `get`) instead:

```
function GetUsername() {
  return database()
      .ref('/users/prathik1')
      .once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => snapshot.val());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to await GetUsername method so that console.log could get executed once data has response

```
async function OwnProfile ({navigation}){
        const data = await GetUsername();
        ….}
```

Comment: Im still getting the same order of output in the terminal :(

Comment: you should use console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) to check-out the response from endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with a callback function in `GetUsername()`, you must return a `Promise` which is to be resolved in the callback function code, like this:

```
async function GetUsername() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        database()
            .ref('/users/prathik1')
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                resolve(snapshot.val());
            });
    });
}
```

With this you should be able to do

```
const result = await GetUsername();
```

**Note**: This is only an incomplete example. Take care of calling `reject()` in case an error occurs.